# TypeError: scatter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data_frame' in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am a noob and was using the first example of Plotly Scatter plots.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()
```

**Error I got**

TypeError: scatter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data_frame'.

**What I tried**

```
fig = px.scatter(data_frame=None,x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
```

This does not solves my problem.
Kindly help

Thank You

Comment: In my environment, the scatterplot appears correctly. The version used is 4.13.0

Comment: Which environment are using my friend?

Comment: @Baazigar if you run `pip show plotly` in your command prompt (not in Python interpreter) what do you get?

Comment: @piterbarg I get, Name: plotly
Version: 4.1.0
Summary: An open-source, interactive graphing library for Python
Home-page: https://plot.ly/python/
Author: Chris P
Author-email: chris@plot.ly
License: MIT
Location: c:\python38\lib\site-packages
Requires: retrying, six
Required-by:

Comment: @Baazigar that's about a year and a bit old. You may want to upgrade `pip install -U plotly` and then your original code should work. Of course there is always a small risk that something may go wrong with an update, so use a virtual environment if you know how to do that

Comment: @piterbarg I updated to latest version but now my webpage that opens automatically on running the code keeps loading.

Comment: @Baazigar sorry to hear... I do not think I can help much here, but it seems somebody else is having a similar problem.. Unless it is you with a different name! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65166468/open-plotly-express-graphs-offiline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plotly.express` module is specifically there to make plotting columns of dataframes easily. As you do not have a dataframe, you shoudl use the 'non-express' (terminology mine) plotly. Try this

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig = fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]))
fig.show()
```

output

[image: plotly plot]

Comment: Thank You for explaining. Can you please tell me where I can read this non express plotly document.

Comment: @Baazigar Main documentation is here: https://plotly.com/python/ which I assume you have already seen. Just look for examples that start `import plotly.graph_objects as go` not `import plotly.express as px`, eg here: https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/  However you may want to update your plotly if you can, because your original example should actually work with the latest plotly as one of the commenters mentioned.