# Open Plotly Express Graphs offiline

Tags: python, plotly

I was trying the Plotly doc first example but my web page that opens automatically on running the below scatter points code just doesn't open.
It keeps loading and loading.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()
```

How can I plot this graph offline like saving it as a file on my PC.

Thank You

Comment: From where are you executing the code? Jupyter notebook? command line?

Comment: If you're using Jupyter notebooks or similar, try this: `from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot, download_plotlyjs` followed by
`init_notebook_mode(connected=True)` and 
`plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)`